# Как создать объект через приватный конструктор?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

У меня есть класс и приватный конструктор, как создать если модификатор доступа не позволяет?

Comment: @AnT, а ведь в плюсах тоже интересные способы есть :) Как минимум два способа - friend и шаблоны.

Comment: Это ваш класс? Если так, то сделайте ему доступный из вне конструктор. Если класс не ваш, убедитесь, что нет других способов создания класса, разработчик не просто так, наверное, запретил создавать экземпляры напрямую. Если это чисто академический интерес, то используйте рефлексию, как вам предложили в ответе.

Comment: Или можно унаследовать класс, и в наследнике использовать свой инициализатор, указав например: `public MyClass() : base() { .. }`

Comment: Уверен -- это акаемический интерес :) Лично мне тоже стало очень интересно, когда я увидел вопрос. Мне вообще не приходило в голову что можно создавать приватный конструктор.

Comment: @NewView, уверены?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, нет :) надо попробовать, задача не типовая, мягко говоря, в такой реализации с приватным конструктором. Но мне кажеться что override инициализатора удастся реализовать при наследовании.

Comment: @NewView, можете не пробовать: `private`-члены не доступны при наследовании по определению. Наследование открывает доступ к `protected`-членам

Comment: Точно! к протектед +

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C# -- полный код консольного приложения https://ideone.com/89wUFX

```
using System;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type type = typeof(Foo);
            Foo f = (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(type, true);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Foo
    {
        private Foo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Private Constructor forefer!");
        }
    }
}
```

Так что ответ на твой вопрос:

```
var f = (SomeClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SomeClass), true);
```

`(SomeClass)` приводим результат создаваемого обьекта к нашему классу..

`Activator.CreateInstance` -- Мы создаем инстанс класса через универсальный метод, через который мы можем создавать инстанс ЛЮБОГО обьекта. Что-то вроде "фабрики".

`typeof(SomeClass)` - берем тип самого класса и высылаем как первый входной параметр метода CreateInstance().

`true`-- второй входной булийный параметр. Он отвечает за то, какой из конструкторов нужно использовать. Фолс = только публичный, Тру = может создавать инстанс как публичный так и приватный. Не пробовал, но... скорее всего он предпочитает приватный, если возможно. Можешь убедится сам.

Comment: Можете ли Вы объяснить что именно делает предложенное Вами решение . Как она работает?

Comment: .........добавил